# 5 circles around a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

[GeoGebra Implementation](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/dsgdew5u)

[image]

> Let ABCD be a cyclic quadrilateral.
>
> 1. A circle passes through A and B and tangent to CD at E.
> 2. A circle passes through B and C and tangent to AD at F.
> 3. A circle passes through C and D and tangent to AB at G.
> 4. A circle passes through D and A and tangent to BC at H.
>
> Prove that EG is perpendicular to FH.

---

I have no idea how to do this problem. I even tried to go onto geogebra and drew the diagram, and it looks extremely messy.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't think that this is true. I draw a cyclic deltoid in GeoGebra and $EG$ and $FH$ were not perpendicular.

Comment: @SMM I think it's because the tangent point is not so accurate.

Comment: It's close to 90º

Comment: Yeah, maybe you are right. There are many circles, did you try inversion?

Comment: @SMM I don't know what inversion is... (I know there is such a thing, but that's all I know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this [construction](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/PPL.shtml) to ensure that the circles pass through the vertices of the quadrilateral and is tangent to the opposite side.

---

Firstly, we need to show that from the diagram below, $EJ=EK$. If you follow the link above, you'll know that the circle passing through $A,B$ is tangent to $CD$ at $K$, and the circle through $C,D$ is tangent to $AB$ at $J$.

[image]

Now, by the [Power of a Point Theorem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/PPower.shtml), we know the following:
$$AE\cdot BE=(AB+BE)\cdot BE= EK^2\\
CE\cdot DE=(CD+CE)\cdot CE=EJ^2 \tag1$$

By virtue of the construction given above, we have $EJ=RE$ and $EK=SE$. We can start by showing:

$$RE\overset{?}{=}EK\tag2$$
Observe that $\triangle ARE$ is right because it is inscribed in the semi-circle $ARE$ and from the construction, we know that $\triangle BRE$ is also right. Meaning, $\triangle DES$ and $\triangle CES$ are right too. 
Thus, we can show that from $(2)$:

$$RE\overset{?}{=}EK\implies RE^2\overset{?}{=}EK^2\\
BE^2+BR^2\overset{?}{=}EK^2\tag3$$

Notice, that from the altitude of the inscribed right triangles $ARE$, we can show that:
$$\frac{BR}{AB}=\frac{BE}{BR}\implies BR^2=AB\cdot BE\\
\tag4$$

Also, notice that from $(1)$, $AB\cdot BE=EK^2-BE^2$. Now plug the new information into $(3)$ and we get:
$$BE^2+AB\cdot BE\overset{?}{=}EK^2\\
BE^2+EK^2-BE^2\overset{?}{=}EK^2\\
EK\overset{\checkmark}{=}EK \\\tag5
q.e.d$$

And since $EJ=RE$, then $EJ=EK$, which means that $RE=SE$ and the circles centered at $E$ are in actuality just one circle.

---

For the complete proof to the problem.
From the image below, and using the proof above, we can show that $FI=FL$ too.

[image]

Firstly, we know that the sum of the angles of the opposite corners of a cyclic quadrilateral is $=180^\circ$. Now suppose $\angle C=180^\circ-\angle A$ and $\angle D=180^\circ -\angle B$.

Since $\angle CBE=180^\circ -B$ and $\angle BCE=A$, then $\angle E=\angle B-\angle A$. Since we have an isosceles triangle $JEK$ (because we have shown earlier that $EJ=EK$), then the base angles must be equal to: 
$$\angle KJE=\angle JKE=\frac{180^\circ-(B-A)}2 \tag6$$

Following the same reasoning, we can show that $\angle FDC=\angle B$ and $DCF=\angle A$ and $\angle F=180^\circ-(A+B)$ and since $\triangle FIL$ is isosceles, thus the base angles are:
$$\angle FIL=\angle ILF=\frac{B+A}2\tag7$$

Finally, look at the quadrilateral $KMLC$. Since the original $\angle C=180^\circ -A$, and from the base angles we derived above, we can write the equation to solve for $\angle KML$ as:
$$\angle JKE+\angle ILF+\angle C+\angle KML=360^\circ\\
\frac{180^\circ-(B-A)}2+\frac{B+A}2+180^\circ-A+\angle KML=360^\circ\\
\angle KML=90^\circ\\\tag8
Q.E.D.$$

Comment: It's an interesting answer but I'm stuck at "...and from the construction, we know that $△BRE$ is also right..." before $(3)$. Would you mind explaining more why $\angle RBE=90^\circ$ from the construction? Thanks!

Comment: @Wong Austin, if you followed the link you'll see that in order to construct the problem, we need to draw a line through $B$ perpendicular to $AE$. *So by definition*, $\angle RBE$ is right.

Comment: Thanks I got it